# Create table as select * from sql server with 'ntext' datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sqldatatypes, create-table

I have a db-link from an oracle 11 database to a SQL server database. I am trying to perform a `ctas` from a table in the SQL server database, however for every table with a column of datatype `ntext` I get the error:

> ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype.

How can I solve this issue? Even if I was willing to forget about those specific columns, I have about 300 tables to perform the same action on.

Comment: [*`ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: That does not help me. I do not care for the fact that in the future Microsoft is going to remove 'ntext' from their system. Right now, I am need of importing this data.

Comment: Well, maybe, if you replaced `ntext` with a more suitable datatype, your import might just work .....

Comment: I agree with you, however I am not in charge, unfortunately, of the sql server. I am simply trying to extract the data from it. Thanks for your help

Comment: You can try casting those columns to nvarchar during your SELECT statements from SQL Server `CAST(ntextColumn AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: Of course you know that select* is a poor programming practice and SQL antipattern even if you have 300 tables. Stop using it in production code.